# Picasso сжимает картинки, как исправить?

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-imageview

Добрый день.

Загружаю картинки через библиотеку Picasso:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Картинки получаются маленькими. 
 если выставляю resize то нарушаю пропорции. И мне нужно чтобы загружалось как есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [Glide](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started) с ней не возникает таких проблем.